# How do I pass variables between classes functions?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Well, I need to get the `price` variable to pass to the Tela 4 function `whatever`. I'm very new to Python and I have no idea how to do this, even tho I imagine it is pretty simple

This is how the code looks right now, feel free to add suggestions on how improve it.

```
class Tela2(Screen):
    def op_dimoff(self):
        self.price = float((int(self.ngd) * 0.87 * 1.75) + self.price_inv)

class Tela4 (Screen):
    def whatever(self):
        tela_two = Tela2
        self.cost_output.text = str(tela_two.price)
```

The ´cost_output´is referring to a kivy label

---

Update:

I think the way @slackmart did it is correct, but still I can’t get the result wanted. I get the error `AttributeError: 'Tela2' object has no attribute 'irrad'` (sorry I didnt post a more complete version of the code, its my first question here and I was afraid to post a long question)

Thats how the code is right now, if you guys could help me finding out a solution:

```
class Tela2(Screen):

   ngd = ObjectProperty()

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(Tela2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.price = 0.0
       self.ngd = 0.0
       self.price_inv = 0.0


   def region_define(self, text):

       self.inorte: float = 4.825
       self.inordeste: float = 5.483
       self.icentro: float = 5.082
       self.isudeste: float = 4.951
       self.isul: float = 4.444

       self.kwh_norte: float = 0.871
       self.kwh_nordeste: float = 0.308
       self.kwh_centro: float = 0.290
       self.kwh_sudeste: float = 0.322
       self.kwh_sul: float = 0.320

       if text == 'Norte':
           self.irrad = self.inorte
           self.kwh = self.kwh_norte

       elif text == 'Nordeste':
           self.irrad = self.inordeste
           self.kwh = self.kwh_nordeste

       elif text == 'Centro-Oeste':
           self.irrad = self.icentro
           self.kwh = self.kwh_centro

       elif text == 'Sudeste':
           self.irrad = self.isudeste
           self.kwh = self.kwh_sudeste

       else:
           self.irrad = self.isul
           self.kwh = self.kwh_sul

   def op_dimoff(self):

   # cálculo da Geração Mínima = (NGD/irrad)
   self.gmin = float(self.ngd/self.irrad)# em W/h

   # dimensionamento potência do inversor
   self.pot_seg = self.gmin * 1.3
   self.inv = (600, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000)
   self.pri_inv = (1434, 1852.2, 1924, 2604, 3899)
   self.x = 0
   for self.x in range(0, len(self.inv)):
       if self.pot_seg <= self.inv[int(self.x)]:
           self.pot_inv = self.inv[int(self.x)]
           self.price_inv = self.pri_inv[int(self.x)]
           break
       else:
           self.x += 1

    self.price = float((int(self.ngd) * 0.87 * 1.75) + self.price_inv)
```

Notes:

> `region_define` is the `on_text` function of a kivy spinner

Comment: change `tela_two = Tela2` to `tela_two = Tela2()`

Comment: @evyllanesc doing as u told I get this " AttributeError: 'Tela2' object has no attribute 'price'"

Comment: This would be easier to answer with a [mcve]. For example Kivy seems to be irrelevant, a bunch of names not defined like `Screen` and `self.ngd`, and your classes get defined but not used.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

There are two options to the solution.

### *Note:*

*It is not recommended to use `tela_two = Tela2()` because you are creating another instance of object, `Tela2` which does not has a view associated to it and different updated values for attributes.*

### Option 1 - using get_screen()

In this option, we retrieve the instantiated object, `Tela2:` using [`get_screen()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current_screen) function so that we can access its method(s) or attributes e.g. `price`. We will make the following enhancements:

#### kv file:

- We [name](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.name) the screens, `name: 'Tela2'` and `name: 'Tela4'` for instantiated objects, `Tela2:` and `Tela4:` respectively.

**Snippets - kv file**

```
ScreenManager:
    Tela2:
        name: 'Tela2'
    ...
    Tela4:
        name: 'Tela4'
```

#### Py file

- Retrieve the instantiated object, `Tela2` using [`get_screen()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current_screen) function

**Snippets - Py file**

```
def whatever(self):
    tela_two = self.manager.get_screen('Tela2')
    self.cost_output.text = str(tela_two.price)
```

or

```
def whatever(self):
    self.cost_output.text = str(self.manager.get_screen('Tela2').price)
```

### Option 2 - using id: tela2

In this option, we add `id: tela2` to instantiated object, `Tela2:` and use `ids.tela2` to access its method(s) or attributes e.g. `price`. We will make the following enhancements:

#### kv file:

- Add `id: tela2` to instantiated object, `Tela2:`

**Snippets - kv file**

```
ScreenManager:
    Tela2:
        id: tela2
    ...
    Tela4:
```

#### Py file

- Replace `tela_two = Tela2` with `tela_two = self.manager.ids.tela2`

**Snippets - Py file**

```
def whatever(self):
    tela_two = self.manager.ids.tela2
    self.cost_output.text = str(tela_two.price)
```

or

```
def whatever(self):
    self.cost_output.text = str(self.manager.ids.tela2.price)
```

## [Kivy ScreenManager » default property manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> Each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the
>   instance of the `ScreenManager` used.

## Example - using id: tela2

The following example illustrates using `get_screen()` function and `ids.tela2` to access attributes defined in object, `Tela2`. It also simulated `on_text` event by invoking `self.region_define('Norte')` and `self.op_dimoff()`.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenManagement>:
    Tela2:
        id: tela2
        name: 'Tela2'
    Tela4:
        name: 'Tela4'

<Tela2>:
    Button:
        text: 'Goto Tela4'
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'Tela4'
<Tela4>:
    on_pre_enter:
        self.whatever()
    Label:
        id: cost_output
        font_size: sp(50)
""")


class Tela2(Screen):
    ngd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tela2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.price = 0.0
        self.ngd = 0.0
        self.price_inv = 0.0

        # simulation
        self.region_define('Norte')
        self.op_dimoff()

    def region_define(self, text):
        self.inorte: float = 4.825
        self.inordeste: float = 5.483
        self.icentro: float = 5.082
        self.isudeste: float = 4.951
        self.isul: float = 4.444

        self.kwh_norte: float = 0.871
        self.kwh_nordeste: float = 0.308
        self.kwh_centro: float = 0.290
        self.kwh_sudeste: float = 0.322
        self.kwh_sul: float = 0.320

        if text == 'Norte':
            self.irrad = self.inorte
            self.kwh = self.kwh_norte

        elif text == 'Nordeste':
            self.irrad = self.inordeste
            self.kwh = self.kwh_nordeste

        elif text == 'Centro-Oeste':
            self.irrad = self.icentro
            self.kwh = self.kwh_centro

        elif text == 'Sudeste':
            self.irrad = self.isudeste
            self.kwh = self.kwh_sudeste

        else:
            self.irrad = self.isul
            self.kwh = self.kwh_sul

    def op_dimoff(self):
        # cálculo da Geração Mínima = (NGD/irrad)
        self.gmin = float(self.ngd / self.irrad)  # em W/h

        # dimensionamento potência do inversor
        self.pot_seg = self.gmin * 1.3
        self.inv = (600, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000)
        self.pri_inv = (1434, 1852.2, 1924, 2604, 3899)
        self.x = 0
        for self.x in range(0, len(self.inv)):
            if self.pot_seg <= self.inv[int(self.x)]:
                self.pot_inv = self.inv[int(self.x)]
                self.price_inv = self.pri_inv[int(self.x)]
                break
            else:
                self.x += 1

        self.price = float((int(self.ngd) * 0.87 * 1.75) + self.price_inv)


class Tela4(Screen):

    def whatever(self):
        # Each screen has by default a roperty manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
        self.ids.cost_output.text = str(self.manager.ids.tela2.price)
        print(f"tela2.irrad={self.manager.ids.tela2.irrad}")
        print(f"tela2.kwh={self.manager.get_screen('Tela2').kwh}")


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm getting this ``` AttributeError: 'Tela4' object has no attribute 'root'```

Comment: Is `Tela4` instantiated as child of `ScreenManager` ?

Comment: Replace `self.root.ids.tela2.price` with `self.parent.ids.tela2.price`. ***Note:** You don't want to use `tela_two = Tela2()` because you are creating another instance of object, `Tela2` and which does not has a view associated to it. You will get AttributeError i.e. no attributes or widgets even it is defined in kv language for `Tela2` .*

Comment: Implementing in my code got me this ```line 264, in whatever
self.ids.cost_output.text = str(self.parent.ids.tela2.price)
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'``` 

Do you have any idea of what this error is about?

Comment: I updated the question with a more complete version of the code, it may be helpful with sorting it out

Comment: "`cost_output`is referring to a kivy label". Where is `cost_output` defined in the kv language?

Comment: "cost_output: cost" where cost is the id of a label

Comment: Since `cost_output` is an `ObjectProperty` and **assuming** that it is defined inside *class rule*, `<Tela4>:`, you have to use `self.cost_output.text = str(self.parent.ids.tela2.price)`

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including kv file and main.py) so that we can reproduce the error.